# How to change angular material sort value from asc/desc to table columnName/-columnName

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have an angular material datatable and I would like to change the sort value from asc/desc to either columnName/ -columnName since I am using Django Rest Framework and on the backend the sorting is by fieldName / -fieldName. Here is my source code, any help on how I will implement it since what I'm trying its not working for me

```
<mat-table class="faith-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="name" matSortDisableClear>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Faith name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let faith"> {{ faith.name }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="editFaith(row)">
                    <mat-icon>launch</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deleteFaith(row.id)">
                    <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort : MatSort;
 ngAfterViewInit(){
    //Server side search
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,'keyup').pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadFaithPage()
      })
    ).subscribe()
    //Reset the paginator after sorting
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0)
    //Merge sort or paginate events, load a new page
    merge(this.sort.sortChange,this.paginator.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadFaithPage())
    ).subscribe()
  }
loadFaithPage(){
    this.dataSource.loadFaith(
      this.input.nativeElement.value,
      this.sort.direction,
      this.paginator.pageIndex,
      this.paginator.pageSize
    )
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to add sorting to the table?

Comment: I would like to change the sort value from asc/desc to use the header value so that if I click the header to sort a header of name it is supposed to send to the backend either name/-name instead of asc/desc